# trying to loop through an array of images but code only displays the number 1 (not even number 0)

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, loops

I'm trying to loop through an array of pictures, but the code it's only displaying 1 of the pictures of the array.

Also, to be more confusing, it's not even displaying the element 0 of the array, but the element 1.

I've been reading about setTimeOut and other methods, but I don't really get the logic yet (javascript newbie).

My final goal it's to display a series of pictures for a specific amount of time (like photograms on a video) when the the mouse is over the element selected.

here's my code:

```
let aboutMePics = ["url('./img/aboutMeStill01.png')", "url('./img/aboutMeStill02.png')"] 

const aboutMe = document.getElementById("aboutMe")
aboutMe.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    for (let i = 0; i < aboutMePics.length; i++) {
        document.body.style.background = aboutMePics[i];
    }
})

aboutMe.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    document.body.style.background = 'initial';
})
```

Comment: You are replacing the body style background with every iteration.

Comment: Is that a bad thing? That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Your question is saying you want to show multiple images.  Replacing a single image, and simultaneously showing multiple images, are two completely different things

Comment: @Taplar "My final goal it's to display a series of pictures for a specific amount of time (like photograms on a video)..."

Comment: So the goal is to make a pseudo-slideshow then.

Comment: Just to be clear, I want only to display 1 image at a time, so the code would indeed replace the image being displayed.

Comment: Yes, exactly, like a pseudo slideshow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// IIFE just for a reduced scope
(function() {
  const aboutMePics = ["url('./img/aboutMeStill01.png')", "url('./img/aboutMeStill02.png')"];
  const aboutMe = document.getElementById("aboutMe");
  let timeout;
  
  function adjustPicture(index) {
    document.body.style.background = aboutMePics[index];
    
    timeout = setTimeout(() => adjustPicture(++index % aboutMePics.length), 3000);
  }

  aboutMe.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    adjustPicture(0);
  });
  
  aboutMe.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    document.body.style.background = 'initial';
  });
})();
```

1. When the mouse enters the element, adjust the picture to pic 0.
2. After adjusting the picture, start a timeout for the next picture for 3 seconds
3. Modulus the index by the number of pictures so the index loops
4. When the mouse leaves the element, clear the timeout and reset the background